# Stop audio playing when another DIV is clicked

Tags: jquery, audio

I was wondering if you could help me? I'm currently creating a small soundboard for a project to help me get to grips with jQuery. I would like audio from the currently active sound file to stop and reset to the beginning when another div is clicked, playing its associated audio file instead. Currently this is how my page is setup:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Parisienne" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Narrow" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/playaudio.js"></script>
    <title>Sample</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="title">Sample</div>
      <div id="accordion">
  <h3 class="accordion-title">Who Are We?</h3>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>
    Content
    </p>
  </div>
  </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="shake-overflow">
            <div id="button-div1"><img id="mobile-img" src="img/ralph-tongue.png" /><p class="button-text">Did He Really?</p></div>
            <div id="button-div2"><img id="mobile-img" src="img/ralph-tongue.png" /><p class="button-text">Train Tracks</p></div>
            <div id="button-div3"><img id="mobile-img" src="img/ralph-tongue.png" /><p class="button-text">Ayyy</p></div>
            <div id="button-div4"><img id="mobile-img" src="img/ralph-tongue.png" /><p class="button-text">Petey</p></div>
          </div>
          <div class="shake-overflow">
            <div id="button-div5"><img id="mobile-img" src="img/ralph-tongue.png" /><p class="button-text">Mr. Raj</p></div>
            <div id="button-div6"><img id="mobile-img" src="img/ralph-tongue.png" /><p class="button-text">Mary</p></div>
            <div id="button-div7"><img id="mobile-img" src="img/ralph-tongue.png" /><p class="button-text">At The Port</p></div>
            <div id="button-div8"><img id="mobile-img" src="img/ralph-tongue.png" /><p class="button-text">Twister</p></div>
          </div>
          <div class="shake-overflow">
            <div id="button-div9"><img id="mobile-img" src="img/ralph-tongue.png" /><p class="button-text">Lewis Poois</p></div>
            <div id="button-div10"><img id="mobile-img" src="img/ralph-tongue.png" /><p class="button-text">You're a Prick!</p></div>
            <div id="button-div11"><img id="mobile-img" src="img/ralph-tongue.png" /><p class="button-text">AHAHAHA</p></div>
            <div id="button-div12"><img id="mobile-img" src="img/ralph-tongue.png" /><p class="button-text">I Lived There</p></div>
          </div>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
  background: url(../img/leather-jacket.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
  background-size:cover;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

img{
  max-width: 100%;
  height:auto;
}

.ui-state-focus { outline: none; }

.accordion-title{
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
  font-family: 'Parisienne', cursive;
  font-weight:normal;
  font-size: 30pt;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

.accordion-title:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-content{
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:2%;
    margin-bottom:2%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.22);
    width:40%;
    padding:15px;
    color:white;
    font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15pt;
}

.accordion-content p {
  -webkit-margin-before: 0em !important;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0em !important;
  text-align: justify;
}

.title{
  font-family: 'Parisienne', cursive;
  font-size: 50pt;
  font-weight:normal;
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.29);
  margin-bottom:3%;
}

.wrapper{
  width:80%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  margin:0 auto;
  border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.22);
  overflow: hidden;
  padding:2%;
  margin-top:2.5%;
}

.wrapper img{
  margin-top:1%;
}

.logo{
  height:auto;
}

.shake-overflow{
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button-text{
  margin:1% 0 1% 0;
}

/*4 Column*/

#button-div1{
  width:20%;
  float:left;
  margin-right:6.53%;
  border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.22);
  margin-bottom:2%;
  font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size:20pt;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
}

#button-div1:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  background: rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.28);
}

#button-div2{
  width:20%;
  float:left;
  margin-right:6.53%;
  border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.22);
  margin-bottom:3%;
  font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size:20pt;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
}

#button-div2:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  background: rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.28);
}

#button-div3{
  width:20%;
  float:left;
  margin-right:6.53%;
  border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.22);
  margin-bottom:3%;
  font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size:20pt;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
}

#button-div3:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  background: rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.28);
}

#button-div4{
  width:20%;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.22);
  margin-bottom:3%;
  font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size:20pt;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
}

#button-div4:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  background: rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.28);
}

#button-div5{
  width:20%;
  float:left;
  margin-right:6.53%;
  border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.22);
  margin-bottom:3%;
  font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size:20pt;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
}

#button-div5:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  background: rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.28);
}

#button-div6{
  width:20%;
  float:left;
  margin-right:6.53%;
  border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.22);
  margin-bottom:3%;
  font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size:20pt;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
}

#button-div6:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  background: rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.28);
}

#button-div7{
  width:20%;
  float:left;
  margin-right:6.53%;
  border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.22);
  margin-bottom:3%;
  font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size:20pt;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
}

#button-div7:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  background: rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.28);
}

#button-div8{
  width:20%;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid white;
  border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.22);
  font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size:20pt;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
}

#button-div8:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  background: rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.28);
}

#button-div9{
  width:20%;
  float:left;
  margin-right:6.53%;
  border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.22);
  font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size:20pt;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
}

#button-div9:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  background: rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.28);
}

#button-div10{
  width:20%;
  float:left;
  margin-right:6.53%;
  border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.22);
  font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size:20pt;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
}

#button-div10:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  background: rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.28);
}

#button-div11{
  width:20%;
  float:left;
  margin-right:6.53%;
  border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.22);
  font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size:20pt;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
}

#button-div11:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  background: rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.28);
}

#button-div12{
  width:20%;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.22);
  font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
  font-size:20pt;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
}

#button-div12:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  background: rgba(54, 54, 54, 0.28);
}

/*2 Column*/

@media screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width:1227px){

.accordion-content{
  width:90%;
}

.accordion-title{
  width:90%;
  margin-bottom:2.5%;
}

.wrapper{
  width:90%;
  margin:0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding:2%;
}

#button-div1{
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8.5%;
  margin-left: 5.5%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}

#button-div2{
  width:40%;
  float:left;
  margin-right:0%;
  margin-bottom:3%;
}

#button-div3{
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8.5%;
  margin-left: 5.5%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}

#button-div4{
  width:40%;
  float:left;
  margin-bottom:3%;
}

#button-div5{
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8.5%;
  margin-left: 5.5%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}

#button-div6{
  width:40%;
  float:left;
  margin-right:0%;
  margin-bottom:3%;
}

#button-div7{
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8.5%;
  margin-left: 5.5%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}

#button-div8{
  width:40%;
  float:left;
  margin-bottom:3%;
}

#button-div9{
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8.5%;
  margin-left: 5.5%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}

#button-div10{
  width:40%;
  float:left;
  margin-right:0%;
}

#button-div11{
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8.5%;
  margin-left: 5.5%;
}

#button-div12{
  width:40%;
  float:left;
}
}

/*1 Column*/
@media screen and (min-width: 250px) and (max-width:600px){

  .shake-overflow{
    overflow:visible;
  }

  .accordion-content {
    width:90%;
  }

  .accordion-title{
    width:90%;
    margin-bottom: 2.5%;
  }

  .wrapper{
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding:2%;
  }

  #button-div1{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-right:0%;
    margin-bottom:3%;
  }

  #button-div2{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-right:0%;
    margin-bottom:3%;
  }

  #button-div3{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-right:0%;
    margin-bottom:3%;
  }

  #button-div4{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:3%;
  }

  #button-div5{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-right:0%;
    margin-bottom:3%;
  }

  #button-div6{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-right:0%;
    margin-bottom:3%;
  }

  #button-div7{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-right:0%;
    margin-bottom:3%;
  }

  #button-div8{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:3%;
  }

  #button-div9{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-right:0%;
    margin-bottom:3%;
  }

  #button-div10{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-right:0%;
    margin-bottom:3%;
  }

  #button-div11{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-right:0%;
  }

  #button-div12{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:0%;
  }
  }

}
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var reallyObj = document.createElement("audio"); reallyObj.src="recordings/Did he really.m4a";  reallyObj.autoPlay=false;  reallyObj.preLoad=true;
  var trainObj = document.createElement("audio"); trainObj.src="recordings/Train.m4a"; trainObj.autoPlay=false; trainObj.preLoad=true;
  var ayyObj = document.createElement("audio"); ayyObj.src="recordings/Ayy.m4a"; ayyObj.autoPlay=false; ayyObj.preLoad=true;
  var peteyObj = document.createElement("audio"); peteyObj.src="recordings/Petey.m4a"; peteyObj.autoPlay=false; peteyObj.preLoad=true;
  var rajObj = document.createElement("audio"); rajObj.src="recordings/Mr. Raj.m4a"; rajObj.autoPlay=false; rajObj.preLoad=true;

  $('#button-div1').on('click', function(){
    reallyObj.play();

  });

  $('#button-div2').on('click', function(){
    trainObj.play();

  });

  $('#button-div3').on('click', function(){
    ayyObj.play();

  });

  $('#button-div4').on('click', function(){
    peteyObj.play();

  });

  $('#button-div5').on('click', function(){
    rajObj.play();

  });

  //div fadeIn
  $('#button-div1').hide().fadeIn(2000);
  $('#button-div2').hide().fadeIn(2200);
  $('#button-div3').hide().fadeIn(2400);
  $('#button-div4').hide().fadeIn(2600);
  $('#button-div5').hide().fadeIn(2800);
  $('#button-div6').hide().fadeIn(3000);
  $('#button-div7').hide().fadeIn(3200);
  $('#button-div8').hide().fadeIn(3400);
  $('#button-div9').hide().fadeIn(3600);
  $('#button-div10').hide().fadeIn(3800);
  $('#button-div11').hide().fadeIn(4000);
  $('#button-div12').hide().fadeIn(4200);

  //logo fadeIn
  $('.logo').hide().fadeIn(2000);

  //title fadeIn
  $('.title').hide().fadeIn(2000);
  $('.accordion-title').hide().fadeIn(2000);

  //wrapper fadeIn
  $('.wrapper').hide().fadeIn(2000);

  //accordion
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      active: false,
      collapsible: true,
      animate: {
        duration: 1000
    }
    });
  });

  //Image shake animation
  $("img").click(function () {
    $(this).effect("shake", { times:3, direction:"up", distance:10 },1000);
  });
});
```

Currently, as you can see, I'm just creating variables, storing audio elements in them and playing them upon the clicking of a div with an ID of what I've set. What would be the best way logically to achieve my goal? Would I be able to add another function which controls the stopping of one file and the playing of a different file depending on what div was clicked or, would it be better if I re-wrote the logic in a different way?

Any help appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, avoiding repetition in the code is always an improvement. You could refactor out some of this code by first adding a common class to all the button divs, say class="button-div", and then replacing all the on divs click event handlers with something like this:

```
var divAudiosMap = {"button-div1": reallyObj, "button-div2": trainObj, ...};

$('.button-div').click(function() {
    var divID = $(this).attr('id');
    divAudiosMap[divID].play();
});
```

Using a map like that always helps with avoiding repetition in general, for example avoiding multiple if statements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot for that. That's cut that section of code into a fraction of what it was. How would I go about stopping one audio file once another div is clicked?